# RxJava & Retrofit2: Chaining dependant Observable results to return a combined pojo 'in one go'

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

(Android/Java professional, RxJava/Lambda novice) I'm trying to create the following pojo:

```
public class ProductCombinedPojo {
    private ProductPojo product;
    private List<TemplatePojo> templates;

    // builder pattern...
}
```

where `ProductPojo` is:

```
public class ProductPojo {
    private List<String> templateUrls; // each url returns a TemplatePojo

    // lots of other stuff...
}
```

I have the following Retrofit2 implementations:

```
@GET
Observable<ProductPojo> getProduct(@Url String url);

@GET
Observable<TemplatePojo> getTemplate(@Url String url);
```

So the first `Observable` returns the `ProductPojo`, the resulting list uf urls within are iterated over and input to the second `Observable` to get the list of `TemplatePojo`s, finally the results are all combined into a new `ProductCombinePojo` using a builder pattern. To further complicate matters, due to the nature of the MVP framework, this all has to be done in a single `Func0<<Observable<ProductCombinedPojo>>` chained RxJava implementation.

I'm having difficulty at the end of the chain cleanly getting the original `ProductPojo` to inject into the builder. Here is my working but ugly solution (assume `mUrl`, `mProductApi` & `mTemplateApi` are all injected and defined as above):

```
@Override
public Observable<ProductCombinedPojo> call() {
    final ProductPojo[] aProductPojo = new ProductPojo[1]; // <------------ Ugly!
    return mProductApi
        .getProduct(mUrl)
        .flatMapIterable(new Func1<ProductPojo, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> call(ProductPojo productPojo) {
                aProductPojo[0] = productPojo;             // <------------ Ugly!
                return productPojo.getTemplateUrls();
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<TemplatePojo>>(){
            @Override
            public Observable<TemplatePojo> call(String templateUrl) {
                return mTemplateApi.getTemplate(templateUrl);
            }
        })
        .toList()
        .map(new Func1<List<TemplatePojo>, ProductCombinedPojo>() {
            @Override
            public ProductCombinedPojo call(List<TemplatePojo> templatePojos) {
                return ProductCombinedPojo.Builder.aProductCombinedPojo()
                        .product(aProductPojo[0])          // <------------ Ugly!
                        .templates(templatePojos)
                        .build();
            }
        });
}
```

How do I rewrite this so that I don't need the ugly `final ProductPojo[]`? After exhuastive searching and reviewing many similar questions on this forum, I think a

```
Func2<ProductPojo, List<TemplatePojo>, ProductCombinedPojo>
```

should be plugged in somewhere but I can't figure out exactly where.  Whilst I am interested in what a Lambda solution will look like, the correct answer will be awarded to any solution using the format above.

Comment: Generally you can combine two (or more) elements without creating an explicit "combined pojo" using Tuples like this one:  http://www.javatuples.org

Comment: You'd still need to somehow bubble the `ProductPojo` down the operator chain, regardless of whether you ultimately returned a explicit pojo or a Tuple. nhaarman mentions the `Pair` Tuple below. I thought about making the Tuple combination in the first `flatMap`. The problem is that the subsequent output of the `flatMapIterable` or `from` needs to be an iterable - and Tuples out-of-the-box aren't iterable (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with every operation like `map` or `flatMap`, you *transform* the input into a new output. If you don't include the input in the output, you won't be able to access that input later on.
This is what you're facing here: you want to be able to access the `ProductPojo` further down the stream.

You could circumvent this by returning a `Pair<ProductPojo, List<String>>` in your `flatMapIterable` function, but this doesn't get any better either.

Instead you can create a new `Observable` in the scope of your `ProductPojo`:

```
public Observable<ProductCombinedPojo> call() {
    return mProductApi.getProduct(mUrl)
          .flatMap(new Func1<ProductPojo, Observable<ProductCombinedPojo>>() {
              @Override
              public Observable<ProductCombinedPojo> call(ProductPojo productPojo) {
                  return combinedPojoFor(productPojo);
              }
          });
}

private Observable<ProductCombinedPojo> combinedPojoFor(final ProductPojo productPojo) {
    return Observable.from(productPojo.getTemplateUrls())
          .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<TemplatePojo>>() {
              @Override
              public Observable<TemplatePojo> call(String templateUrl) {
                  return mTemplateApi.getTemplate(templateUrl);
              }
          })
          .toList()
          .map(new Func1<List<TemplatePojo>, ProductCombinedPojo>() {
              @Override
              public ProductCombinedPojo call(List<TemplatePojo> templatePojos) {
                  return ProductCombinedPojo.Builder.aProductCombinedPojo()
                        .product(productPojo)
                        .templates(templatePojos)
                        .build();
              }
          });
}
```

Using lambdas:

```
public Observable<ProductCombinedPojo> call() {
    return mProductApi.getProduct(mUrl)
        .flatMap((productPojo) -> combinedPojoFor(productPojo));
}

private Observable<ProductCombinedPojo> combinedPojoFor(final ProductPojo productPojo) {
    return Observable.from(productPojo.getTemplateUrls())
        .flatMap((templateUrl) -> mTemplateApi.getTemplate(templateUrl))
        .toList()
        .map((templatePojos ->
            ProductCombinedPojo.Builder.aProductCombinedPojo()
                .product(productPojo)
                .templates(templatePojos)
                .build()
        ));
}
```

Comment: This is way, way neater than my solution - although it's essentially the same thing (ProductPojo stored in a final). I was really hoping that there would be something in the vast arsenal of observable operators that would cater for this scenario. Thanks for taking the time and effort to make such a clear answer. I will almost certainly mark it as accepted.